# Is it possible to make multiprocessing.Pool (python 3.6) run on first few inputs in interactive mode?

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I want to use multiprocessing.Pool in python 3.6 to run a function f in parallel, for different inputs. I also want to use jupyter notebook to do this, because I want to use the output to try lots of different things. I know this is [not supported](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers). The subprocesses that I launch use variables created in the program, prior to the invocation of multiprocessing.Pool. i.e. the shared variables exist before the subprocesses are launched (I am using a linux platform). When I launch this, I observe that for the first one or two inputs, the function does not execute. It enters the function, runs one or two lines, and then seems to hang (I keep waiting indefinitely in pool.join()). The function finishes successfully for all other inputs - I have a print statement at the beginning and end of the function, so I know for which inputs it has finished. I've tried removing the first two inputs, but the issue is not dependent on the input values. It seems to be an artifact of using multiprocessing.Pool in interactive mode. As a hack, I padded the front of my inputs with some dummy inputs, and in the function the first thing I check is that if its a dummy input, then just return None. This seems to work (pool.join() finishes and I get control back). Is there a better way to do  the same thing, without this ugly hack?

Also, I don't understand the reason for the restriction to non-interactive mode, mentioned [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-spawn-and-forkserver-start-methods). Can someone please explain this?

More info:
The function that I am calling outputs a large pandas dataframe.

Comment: How about you post a [mcve] of the problem instead of wall of text - it's much easier to see from the code what are you trying to achieve and where you got stuck than by merely describing the problem.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem with a smaller example. If I have a function that does much less computation and transfers much less data, I don't see this issue.